# Web-mobile programming

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

Can anyone name a few features that are specific/suitable for mobile web programming using html5, css and javascript?.

where can I find the compatibility list for each browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mechanisms used in mobile Web programming:

- [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)
- [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)
- [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Good browser compatibility lists:

- [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)
- [Mobile HTML5](http://mobilehtml5.org/)
- [ES6 Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Online tools to test your code on various mobile browsers:

- [MobileTest.me](http://mobiletest.me/)
- [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)
- [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/)

Online tools to test your code for mobile friendliness:

- [Google Mobile-Friendly Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for a list of features and their compatibility list and caniuse.com has it all.